# Can this jquery script be written more elegantly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Both blocks of code in Jquery section are doing exactly the same thing(hiding each other's respective form and changing their own background color).
Code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#messageForm').hide();
  $('#message').click(function() {
    $("#message").children().css("background-color", "");
    $("#creative").children().css("background-color", "#a6a6a6");
    $('#messageForm').show();
    $('#creativeForm').hide();

  });
  $('#creative').click(function() {
    $("#message").children().css("background-color", "#a6a6a6");
    $("#creative").children().css("background-color", "");
    $('#messageForm').hide();
    $('#creativeForm').show();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="message">message</button>
<button id="creative">creative</button>


<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div id="creativeForm">
    <textarea name="" class="form-control" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
    <div class="clear10"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="btn_compaign_repot col-sm-12" style="height:50px; line-height:45px;">Send Creative</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="messageForm">
    <textarea name="" class="form-control" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
    <div class="clear10"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="btn_compaign_repot col-sm-12" style="height:50px; line-height:45px;">Send Message</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it can be written more elegantly. Also, the elements `#message` and `#creative` don't exist in your html.

Comment: I'd like to see some more elegance in this as well. Very curious.

Comment: Since you use `$().show()` with no other arguments, it's almost equivalent to just setting `display:none` and `display: block`. So your function can be replaced by toggling a css class that has the correct color and `display:block`.

Comment: @Moob message and creative are two buttons on top.

Comment: @IrfanAnwar you should update your question to reflect this. With #message and #creative shown in the HTML the sample code might work and you could get working demos in the replies.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Using one click handler, set defaults for both elements, then override the defaults for the clicked element (`this`):

```
$('#creative, #message').click(function() {
  $("#creative, #message").css("background-color", "#a6a6a6");
  $("#creativeForm, #messageForm").hide();

  $(this).css("background-color", "");
  $('#' + this.id + 'Form').show();
});
```

(Note that your button elements don't have any children.)

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#messageForm').hide();

  $('#creative, #message').click(function() {
    $("#creative, #message").css("background-color", "#a6a6a6");
    $("#creativeForm, #messageForm").hide();

    $(this).css("background-color", "");
    $('#' + this.id + 'Form').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="message">message</button>
<button id="creative">creative</button>


<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div id="creativeForm">
    <textarea name="" class="form-control" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
    <div class="clear10"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="btn_compaign_repot col-sm-12" style="height:50px; line-height:45px;">Send Creative</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="messageForm">
    <textarea name="" class="form-control" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
    <div class="clear10"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="btn_compaign_repot col-sm-12" style="height:50px; line-height:45px;">Send Message</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should be `$("#creativeForm, #messageForm").hide();` ?

Answer (score 1):

*Slightly* more elegant JS solution:

```js
$(function(){

  var $forms = $("#creativeForm, #messageForm")
        .hide(),
      $buttons = $("#creative, #message")
        .css("background-color", "grey")
        .click(function(){
          $buttons.css("background-color", "grey");
          $forms.hide();
          $(this).css("background-color", "green");
          $('#' + this.id + 'Form').show();
        });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="message">message</button>
<button id="creative">creative</button>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div id="creativeForm">
    <textarea name="" class="form-control" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
    <div class="clear10"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="btn_compaign_repot col-sm-12" style="height:50px; line-height:45px;">Send Creative</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="messageForm">
    <textarea name="" class="form-control" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
    <div class="clear10"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="btn_compaign_repot col-sm-12" style="height:50px; line-height:45px;">Send Message</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**But you can do all this in CSS**
(which is *definitely* more elegant)...

```css
label[for=message],
label[for=creative] {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}

#messageForm,
#creativeForm {
  display: none;
}

#message,
#creative {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%
}

#message:checked~label[for=message],
#creative:checked~label[for=creative] {
  background:green;
}

#message:checked~#messageForm,
#creative:checked~#creativeForm {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <input type="radio" name="showForm" id="message" />
  <input type="radio" name="showForm" id="creative" />
  <label for="message">message</label>
  <label for="creative">creative</label>
  <div id="creativeForm">
    <textarea name="" class="form-control" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
    <div class="clear10"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="btn_compaign_repot col-sm-12" style="height:50px; line-height:45px;">Send Creative</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="messageForm">
    <textarea name="" class="form-control" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
    <div class="clear10"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="btn_compaign_repot col-sm-12" style="height:50px; line-height:45px;">Send Message</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

N.B If you want one of the forms visible by default simply preselect the appropriate `input`. EG: `<input type="radio" name="showForm" id="message" checked="checked" />`. Also, if your form is submitted but returns with an error it is easy to reestablish the active form and values.

Answer (score 0):

At least on the js side, since each of the `click` functions are effectively doing the same thing, you can abstract that into its own function that takes in some variables. I'm also not seeing the "creative" and "message" id's in your HTML...are they supposed to also be "creativeForm" and "messageForm"?

```
function swapShowHide(show, hide) {
    $(show).show().children().css( "background-color", "" );
    $(hide).hide().children().css( "background-color", "#a6a6a6" );
}

$('#creativeForm').click(swapShowHide.bind('#creativeForm', '#messageForm');
$('#messageForm').click(swapShowHide.bind('#messageForm', '#creativeForm');
```

Comment: can you do  `$(show).show().children().css( "background-color", "" );` ? just outa interest?

Comment: yes, I believe you can also do that, as jquery funs usually return jquery objects! I haven't personally tried this though

Comment: chaining is more efficient than searching dom for same element multiple times

Comment: Try caching the element in a variable if that's a concern. No need to select the same JQuery node each time again.